# Mutually exclusive arrays from an array of object based on some condition in python

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

As the title explains I want to create two mutually exclusive list (list1 and list2) from an array of objects matching some condition below is an example of objects

```
reviews = [
            ...
            {
              ...
              "mood": "happy"
              ...
            },
            {
              ...
              "mood": "sad"
              ...
            },
            {
              ...
              "mood": "neutral"
              ...
            },
            ...
          ]
```

Now I am getting two moods from user as m1 and m2, I am looping over reviews array and adding each object to list1 if m1 == mood and to list2 if m2 == mood repectively.
list1 and list2 should have at most 5 reviews and they shouldn't be empty. It is guaranteed that m1 and m2 will always match reviews.

```
for review in reviews:
 if review['mood'] == m1:
   list1.append(review)
 if review['mood'] == m2:
   list2.append(review)
```

Lets assume that user gives m1 and m2 both as "happy" now both list will have same reviews. I want them to be exclusive list that means if a review is on list1 it shouldn't be on list2. I have solved this using a map object that will contain review id of reviews added to list1 and I will only add review to list2 if it's key-value pair is None.
But i feel there could be a better approach to this.

Comment: You need to provide a sample output of what you are expecting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I think you need maintain a counter and that would solve your problem.

```
#m1==m2
count=0
for review in reviews:
    if count%2==0:
        list1.append(review)
    else:
        list2.append(review)
    count+=1
```

Let me know this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way would be to use `elif`:

```
for review in reviews:
 if review['mood'] == m1:
   list1.append(review)
 elif review['mood'] == m2:
   list2.append(review)
```

In case the first `if` condition is true, the second condition will not even be checked.

Comment: That will make list2 empty isn't it?

Comment: If `m1 == m2` yes, `list2` will remain empty, but that's the desired behaviour is it not?

Comment: no please read the question they must not be empty

Comment: Which should be in `list1` and which in `list2`? If you can specify that exactly, the actual solution is likely to be trivial.

Comment: there is no criteria just that they should be mutually exclusive.